# Adding a Null option to time trigger to avoid "....failed to finish successfully" error report

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

**Aim:** to run script on time basis for new emails and send to Google Sheet tab
**Issue:** script will run successfully but will create "...failed to finish successfully" report if there are no unread Gmail threads to find when I set up a timed trigger to monitor for new Gmails, with the specific thread (Spreadsheet Name).

How would I add a "null" filter to stop the errors occurring?

Non programmer so apologies for the code!

```
function getGmailEmails(){

var spreadSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var subLabelVariable = "xxxxx" + spreadSheetName;

var label =  GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(subLabelVariable);

var threads =  label.getThreads();
var sentToSheet = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("SenttoSheet");

  
  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages =  threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.isUnread()){
        extractDetails(message);
        GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
      }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(sentToSheet); 
    
  }
}
function extractDetails(message){
  var dateTime = message.getDate();
  var subjectText = message.getSubject();
  var senderDetails = message.getFrom()
  var sentTo =message.getTo();
  var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody();
  var messageLink = message.getId();
  var emailLink = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/" + messageLink;
  var type = "From: " + senderDetails + '\n' + "SentTo: " + sentTo + '\n' + emailLink;
  var contactHistorySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var contactHistorySheetName =  contactHistorySheet.getSheetByName("xxxxxxxx"); contactHistorySheetName.appendRow([dateTime, type, subjectText, bodyContents]);

}
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of the full script? What is the `extractDetails` function?

Comment: Hi, updated the code to show extractDetails function, it just loops through and sends the data to a specific sheet name on new row

Comment: Does it happens all the time? How have you set up your trigger?

Comment: Hi, just a time-based trigger (every 15mins).

Comment: I have tried it with a trigger (every minute) and did not get the error you are having, with all the mails already read and even without any mails on the tag. Does it happens always or just sometimes?

Comment: It's random, some sheets (many with code now in use), I have settled to just delete the script report error emails each morning.

Comment: What do you mean by `some sheets (many with code now in use)`, has deleting the report each morning solved the issue? If so, please add it as an answer so more people can benefit from it.

Comment: poor wording, some spreadsheets not sheets I meant to say. Currently I just delete the morning email error reports as received.

Comment: Resolved: the trigger was set to 15mins checking cycle and it was invoking too many times during the 24 period. Not set to hourly check.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: the trigger was set to 15mins checking cycle and it was invoking too many times during the 24 period. Not set to hourly check.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(threads) {
for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages =  threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.isUnread()){
        extractDetails(message);
        GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
      }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(sentToSheet); 
    
  }
}
```